# windows authentication in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

In Asp.net Application for windows authentication

In aspx page

```
asp:Label runat="server" ID="windows"
```

aspx.cs page

```
windows.Text = User.Identity.Name;
```

webconfig:

```
authentication mode="Windows"
```

but authentication is not performed what problem ??

Comment: "authentication is not performed"..are you getting any errors? or how are you saying that the authentication is not performed?

Comment: if authentication performed means lable show my local system name. . but that lable did't show anything

Comment: Have you disabled the 'Annonymous authentication" in your web server?

Answer (score 0):

Add the following in your web.config under system.web to make sure that the windows authorization is triggered:

```
<authorization>
    <allow users="?" />
</authorization>
```

Answer (score 0):

> Because Integrated Windows Authentication uses the current Windows
>   user information on the client computer for the authentication, **it
>   does not immediately prompt the user for a user name and password**.
>   However, if the authentication exchange cannot identify the user, a
>   dialog box appears that prompts the user for a Windows user account
>   user name and password

Source: [How to implement Windows authentication and authorization in ASP.NET](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/323176)

Try adding the following block to see if it's working

```
<authorization>
    <deny users="*" />
</authorization>
```

After adding this, run the application and you should get *HTTP 401 - Access is denied error*.

You can customize authorization from then on.

**UPDATE:**

Here's a different approach and how to configure it via IIS management console:

1. Deploy your site to IIS
2. Click on your site and select **Authentication**
3. Disable Anonymous Authentication and enable Windows Authentication as shown in the image below

[image]

4. Go back to features and select **.NET Authorization Rules**. Here you can add allow/deny rules on a role or user basis.

[image]

To test your current code deny anonymous users and allow all. When you connect to your application you should be able to use the Windows user you used to log in.

Answer (score 0):

Your `web.config` wants to contain like this:

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <authentication mode="Windows" />
    <anonymousIdentification enabled="false" />
    <authorization>
      <deny users="?" />
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

This will force all users to use their windows/Active Directory login. A 401 Access Denied error will be given to those who don't log in.

Comment: You may need to update your settings in your browser. For IE/Chrome go into settings, Security tab and add the site to the list of "Trusted Sites". Then Click the "Custom Level" button.  Scroll right down to the bottom of the Security Settings dialogue, you'll see a section "User Authentication", make sure it's not on Anonymous Logon.