# how to find client side windows authenticated user name in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

My code is deployed in the server, now in the client side when a user enters in to the website, then the user's windows authenticated user name should be displayed. Kindly help.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32759152/windows-authentication-in-asp-net

Answer (score 0):

You can read the windows authenticated user with

```
string authuser;
authuser = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;
```

After that you can read more informations about the user from the active directory.

Comment: It gives me the server side user name but not the client side.

Comment: @SibashritPattnaik Have you updated the settings in web.config or enabled windows authentication from IIS?

Comment: No. Could you please tell me the whole procedure to do that.

Comment: @SibashritPattnaik check the link added in the comment on the question. It has an answer with the detailed steps. Please try searching before posting question.

Comment: Just commenting to add that in MVC the class Controller has this property: `public IPrincipal User { get; } ` `// The user security information for the current HTTP request.`